# How to Make my Android App FullScreen via Android Manifest?

Tags: android, sdk

How do I do this? Any suggestions? BTW I am using SDK with AIDE.

Comment: there's nothing to do with IDE. add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar."` in your activity tag in Manifest.xml

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Go into the manifest and use a full screen theme.

```
 <activity
       android:name=".Foo"   
       android:label="@string/foo" 
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

Comment: This crashes my app every single time.

Comment: Your Activity's cant be AppCompatActivity, instead use `public class MainActivity extends Activity {`

Comment: Not working if class extends AppCompactActivity class

Answer (score 14):

This code makes the current Activity Full-Screen. No Status-Bar or anything except the Activity-Window!

```
    public class FullScreen extends Activity {
      @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
} 
}
```

Edit for AppCompactActivity

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I'm using similar and that not allowing to scroll page which have few inout filed. Any suggestion !!

Comment: have you added scrollView as your root layout?

Comment: Yes, I'm using fragment and that layout has Scroll view as root view.

Comment: It took 30mins to see this, but it has to "extend Activity" and not "AppCompatActivity"

Answer (score 7):

If you want a full screen put this attribute in `<activity />` or `<application />` tag in your Manifest file

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: It is not real fullscreen. I am missing one dynamically placed button at the bottom. I am emulating my development an genymotion 1280 X 800.
And I place my elements into a absolute layout using for example this line.  "b.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(150,150,50,50));"  Can it bee, that I MUST use another layout due to this ?

Answer (score 3):

Agree with the above answer given by [SquiresSquire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12593222/996493). Just adding little more information in the answer i would like to present my answer.

You can make your application full screen in two ways,

- Making Full Screen any particular Activity

  add theme element in activity tag

  ```
  <activity
           android:name=".YourActivityName"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.">
  ```
- Making Full Screen whole application

  add theme element with application tag

  ```
  <application
           android:icon="@drawable/icon"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.">
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To set your Application or any individual activity display in Full Screen mode,

Insert the code in AndroidManifest .xml file

```
@android:style /Theme. NoTitle Bar.Fullscreen
```

Answer (score -1):

This works well for me.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```