# Camera Preview landscape view not fullscreen

Tags: android

I've searched stack exchange and google for a solution but I can't seem to find one that works. My camera preview works beautifully in portrait, but when the orientation switches to landscape, it is not full screen and is highly distorted. I'm also trying to implement this as a fragment

Here is my code

CameraFragment.java

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PictureCallback {
public static final String TAG = CameraFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int PICTURE_SIZE_MAX_WIDTH = 1280;
private static final int PREVIEW_SIZE_MAX_WIDTH = 640;

private int cameraId;
private Camera camera;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private CameraFragmentListener listener;
private int displayOrientation;
private int layoutOrientation;

private CameraOrientationListener orientationListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);

    if(!(activity instanceof CameraFragmentListener)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must implement CameraFragmentListener interface");
    }

    listener = (CameraFragmentListener)activity;
    orientationListener = new CameraOrientationListener(activity);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    CameraPreview previewView = new CameraPreview(getActivity());

    previewView.getHolder().addCallback(this);

    return previewView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    orientationListener.enable();

    try {
        camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't open camera with id " + cameraId, exception);

        listener.onCameraError();
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    orientationListener.disable();

    if(camera != null) {
        stopCameraPreview();
        camera.release();
    }
}

private synchronized void startCameraPreview() {
    determineDisplayOrientation();
    setupCamera();

    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't start camera preview due to Exception", exception);

        listener.onCameraError();
    }
}

private synchronized void stopCameraPreview() {
    try {
        camera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Exception during stopping camera preview");
    }
}

public void determineDisplayOrientation() {
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, cameraInfo);

    int rotation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees  = 0;

    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    int displayOrientation;

    if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        displayOrientation = (cameraInfo.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        displayOrientation = (360 - displayOrientation) % 360;
    } else {
        displayOrientation = (cameraInfo.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }

    this.displayOrientation = displayOrientation;
    this.layoutOrientation  = degrees;

    camera.setDisplayOrientation(displayOrientation);
}

public void setupCamera() {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    Camera.Size bestPreviewSize = determineBestPreviewSize(parameters);
    Camera.Size bestPictureSize = determineBestPictureSize(parameters);

    parameters.setPreviewSize(bestPreviewSize.width, bestPreviewSize.height);
    parameters.setPictureSize(bestPictureSize.width, bestPictureSize.height);

    camera.setParameters(parameters);
}

private Camera.Size determineBestPreviewSize(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

    return determineBestSize(sizes, PREVIEW_SIZE_MAX_WIDTH);
}

private Camera.Size determineBestPictureSize(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();

    return determineBestSize(sizes, PICTURE_SIZE_MAX_WIDTH);
}

protected Camera.Size determineBestSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int widthThreshold) {
    Camera.Size bestSize = null;

    for (Camera.Size currentSize : sizes) {
        boolean isDesiredRatio = (currentSize.width / 4) == (currentSize.height / 3);
        boolean isBetterSize = (bestSize == null || currentSize.width > bestSize.width);
        boolean isInBounds = currentSize.width <= PICTURE_SIZE_MAX_WIDTH;

        if (isDesiredRatio && isInBounds && isBetterSize) {
            bestSize = currentSize;
        }
    }

    if (bestSize == null) {
        listener.onCameraError();

        return sizes.get(0);
    }

    return bestSize;
}

public void takePicture(){
    orientationListener.rememberOrientation();

    camera.takePicture(null, null, this);
}

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    int rotation = (displayOrientation + orientationListener.getRememberedOrientation() + layoutOrientation) % 360;

    if(rotation != 0){
        Bitmap oldBitmap = bitmap;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotation);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false);
        oldBitmap.recycle();
    }
    listener.onPictureTaken(bitmap);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    this.surfaceHolder = holder;

    startCameraPreview();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    //fragment handles release
}
}
```

CameraFragmentListener.java

```
public interface CameraFragmentListener {
public void onCameraError();

public void onPictureTaken(Bitmap bitmap);
}
```

CameraOrientationListener.java

```
public class CameraOrientationListener extends OrientationEventListener {
private int currentNormalizedOrientation;
private int rememberNormalizedOrientation;

public CameraOrientationListener (Context context){
    super(context, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
    if(orientation != ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN){
        currentNormalizedOrientation = normalize(orientation);
    }
}

private int normalize(int degrees){
    if(degrees > 315 || degrees <= 45)
        return 0;
    if(degrees > 45 && degrees <= 135)
        return 90;
    if(degrees > 135 && degrees <= 225)
        return 180;
    if(degrees > 225 && degrees <= 315)
        return 270;

    throw new RuntimeException("Wrong bruh");
}

public void rememberOrientation(){
    rememberNormalizedOrientation = currentNormalizedOrientation;
}

public int getRememberedOrientation(){
    return rememberNormalizedOrientation;
}
}
```

CameraPreview.java

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView {
private static final double ASPECT_RATIO = 3.0 / 4.0;

public CameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public CameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CameraPreview(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    if (width > height * ASPECT_RATIO) {
        width = (int) (height * ASPECT_RATIO + .5);
    } else {
        height = (int) (width / ASPECT_RATIO + .5);
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
}
```

CameraActivity.java

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements CameraFragmentListener {
public static final String TAG = CameraActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int PICTURE_QUALITY = 90;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
}

@Override
public void onCameraError(){
    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.toast_error_camera_preview), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    finish();
}

public void takePicture(View view){
    view.setEnabled(false);

    CameraFragment fragment = (CameraFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.camera_fragment);

    fragment.takePicture();
}

public void onPictureTaken(Bitmap bitmap){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
            ),
            getString(R.string.app_name)
    );

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            showSavingPictureErrorToast();
            return;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile = new File(
            mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "MUSTACHE_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg"
    );

    try {
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, PICTURE_QUALITY, stream);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        showSavingPictureErrorToast();

        Log.w(TAG, "IOException during saving bitmap", exception);
        return;
    }

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
            this,
            new String[] { mediaFile.toString() },
            new String[] { "image/jpeg" },
            null
    );

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PhotoActivity.class);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(mediaFile));
    startActivity(intent);

    finish();
}

private void showSavingPictureErrorToast() {
    Toast.makeText(this, getText(R.string.toast_error_save_picture), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Sorry for the extremely long post, I just want to be as thorough as possible. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: To force fullscreen, look at this answer           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593177/how-to-make-my-android-app-fullscreen-via-android-manifest

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do it. Instead of being black around the small preview, the rest of the screen turns white

Answer (score 0):

If you want your preview to be full screen, you should set the full screen flag in your activity before you call `setContentView`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
}
```