# app with custom theme in android, error: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: java, android, xml, themes

here is my xml manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.subhunter">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SubHunter">
        <activity android:name=".SubHunter"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here are 2 theme files (came by default with the empty activity):
theme:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.SubHunter" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

theme (night):

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.SubHunter" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

error has many lines, beginning with:

2021-03-21 13:40:10.574 18926-18926/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.subhunter, PID: 18926
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.subhunter/com.example.subhunter.SubHunter}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

not sure what to do, new to android, trying to build a game with canvas with custom theme, no xml file for game.

Answer (score 0):

There is a forum with some answers to your Question take a look at this forum:

[How to Make my Android App FullScreen via Android Manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593177/how-to-make-my-android-app-fullscreen-via-android-manifest)

Most of them say that you need to change the ActivityCompat to Activity and add the code in the onCreate method.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

another option as you can see in the forum is to apply some some styles in the theme:

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

If the problem persists we can investigate.