# How to delete the status bar in Android 12

Tags: java, android

I'm an Android mapper and I'm trying to edit the UI settings in such a way that they can't download the status bar

In practice I could not find the file that could prevent the download but only the file where the tiles can be edited

Comment: Not sure if those old answers still work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12593177/150978